# How to iterate through the synset list generated from wordnet using python 3.4.2

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, wordnet, sentiment-analysis

I am using wordnet to find the synonyms for a particular word as shown below

```
synonyms = wn.synsets('good','a')
```

where wn is wordnet. This returns a list of synsets like

```
Synset('good.a.01')    
Synset('full.s.06')    
Synset('good.a.03')    
Synset('estimable.s.02')    
Synset('beneficial.s.01')
```

etc...

How to iterate through each synset and get the name and the pos tag of each synset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name and the pos tag of each synset like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

synonyms = wn.synsets('good','a')

for synset in synonyms:
    print(synset.name())
    print(synset.pos())
```

The name is the combination of word, pos and sense, such as 'full.s.06'. If you just want the word, you can split on the dot '.' and take the first element:

```
print(synset.name().split('.')[0]
```

Comment: I have tried this option and it works !!! Is there any direct way to fetch the word ?

Comment: I don't think so. See the documentation: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset

Comment: By the way, if this helped you, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark. In this way, other people will know this answer was correct (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I am using this in my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

word = input()

for syn in wordnet.synsets(word):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        print(syn.pos()) 
        print(l.name())
```

The syn.pos() can be called outside the inner loop as well, because each lemma contains words with same pos.